# Issue Google maps API on iOS 11 with Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, core-data, cocoapods

I'm trying to set a map in a view in my app and I got this problem:

CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/35C61A40-48B9-40E0-A6F9-AB7492A15009/simply-convertor.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/35C61A40-48B9-40E0-A6F9-AB7492A15009/simply-convertor.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/35C61A40-48B9-40E0-A6F9-AB7492A15009/simply-convertor.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'

I add an empty view to my ViewContoroller and change it's type to GMSMapView.
And in viewDidLoad method I create a new map from location and init my main mapView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        locationAuthStatus()
        print(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 31.9650070083707, longitude: 34.7899029677496, zoom: 6.0)
        let map = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        self.mapView = map

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 31.9650070083707, longitude: 34.7899029677496)
        marker.title = "Home"
        marker.snippet = "Home"
        marker.map = mapView
    }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: The error message suggests that you've left out some of the files that the Google maps frameworks needs. Google maps is having an internal error because it can't find a file that it expects to exist.

Comment: how can i fix it? I installed it via CococaPods

Comment: I could not say, which is why I left a comment rather than an answer. The error message strongly suggests it's not a Core Data problem, but that Core Data is having trouble because crucial files are missing.

Comment: It seems like an issue of google map SDK, the issue was reported to Google and here is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64504919. Till now there is no solution, hope it will have solved soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find my problem.. it appears I misunderstood the initialliztion of a GMSMapView and not initialize it correct..

From other post the CoreData error that I mention is a problem of Google's API and it doesn't affect the app.

Comment: I am having the same warning. Can you please share your solution?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Can you please share your solution? Thank you

Comment: I am having the same warning. Can you please share your solution?

Comment: I am having the same warning. Can you please share your solution?

Comment: I am having the same warning. Can you please share your solution?

Comment: try use Google maps "2.5.0", recently they have fixed this issue